# How to linearise a function in its parameters.

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

## Question

Assume we have a function $f(x, \Theta) \in \mathbb R$, where $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is the function input, $\theta\in\mathbb R^p$ is the collection of the function parameters $\theta_i \in \mathbb R$ and $p,n\in\mathbb N$. I want a approximation of this function, such that it is linear in its *parameters* $\theta_i$. How can I do this?

I was thinking using an expansion, but this seems to fail for me, since I do not have an expansion point available (see section Motivation), so I am happy with another method.

## Motivation

I want to be able to fit a function based on a [linear least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) cost function using closed form
$$
\hat {\Theta}=(X^{T} \cdot  X)^{-1} X^{T} \cdot y
$$
where $X$ is the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) (not necessarily directly $x$ from $f(x)$, but $x$ transformed without using function parameters, e.g. $exp(x)$ or $x^2$).
Please assume that using iterative optimization method (e.g. Netwon's method) is not an option, otherwise this would change this question entirely in the first place.

**For the curious regarding the computer science aspects:**
For the linear least-squares I have between 500 and 60000 multivariate data points with dimensionality between 2 and 64 - it is very case depended.
I have to run between 50.000 and 1 million of those linear-least-squares (maybe later even more.)

## What I have tried so far (an example): Polynomial approximation

(*I am not interested in the Gaussian, this is just an example.*)

For example, Gaussian normal distribution
$$
a_g \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot ((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2) + b_g
$$
is linear in $a,b$, but not $\mu,\sigma$, where $\Theta = (a_g,\mu,\sigma,b_g)$,
while the quadratic function 
$$
-a_q \cdot (x-\mu)^2 + b_q
$$
is linear in all it parameters $\Theta = (a_q,\mu,b_q)$ and it somewhat approximates the Gaussian close to $\mu$, but not at all otherwise.

This gave me the idea to use Taylor series expansion (omitting subscript)
\begin{align}
&a \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2) + b \\
=\ & a \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x_0-\mu)^2/\sigma^2) + b \\
-\ & a \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x_0-\mu)^2/\sigma^2) \cdot (x_0-\mu)/\sigma^2 \cdot (x-x_0)
\end{align}
which obviously does not produce a function that is linear in the parameters.

So I had the idea to use Taylor expansion on the parameters $\mu,\sigma$ instead, but I would not know at which point $\Theta_0$

\begin{align}
&a \cdot \Big( \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2) \Big) + b \\
=\ a \cdot \Big( & \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x-\mu_0)^2/\sigma_0^2) \\
&  + \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x-\mu_0)^2/\sigma_0^2)
\cdot (x-\mu_0)/\sigma_0^2
\cdot (\mu-\mu_0) \\
& +  \exp(-0.5 \cdot (x-\mu_0)^2/\sigma_0^2)
\cdot (x-\mu_0)^2/\sigma_0^3
\cdot (\sigma-\sigma_0) \Big) + b
\end{align}

However, I need to have a good guess for $\Theta_0$.

## What I have tried so far (an example): Non-polynomial approximation

Another option to approximate
$$
a_g \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot ((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2) + b_g
$$
would be to use another Gaussian
$$
a_g \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot x^2) + b_g
$$
which would approximate the original Gaussian well, if the original values of $\mu,\sigma$ are close to $0,1$, respectively.

That gave me the idea to use an approximation that is, unlike Taylor expansion, not restricted to polynomial terms (and thus a relaxation of constraints), but which must be linear in its model parameters everywhere (thus adding constraints), unlike Taylor, which needs to be cut off after the first-derivative-terms.

Maybe such an approximation might not require a $\Theta_0$?

## In case the question cannot be answered in general...

... (which would bring the greatest advantage to the community though):

I am currently mostly interested in the function
$$
f(x, \Theta) = a \cdot \exp(-0.5 \cdot ((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2)  − \log\left(((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2 + 1\right) + b
$$
where $\Theta = (a_q,\mu,\sigma,b_q)$.